# How to set default font, or default style in Graphviz's Dot language

Tags: fonts, graphviz

It seems, every tutorial every example scripts explicitly states what font should be used for each node/arrow.

Instead, I'd like to specify default font which all arrows and nodes use only once (may at the beginning of file, or maybe separate style file sheets)

[link](https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fontname/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put something like this at the top level:

```
node [fontname="default-node-font"];
edge [fontname="default-edge-font"];
```

I can't find this explicitly in the online manual (it's alluded to under https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html#lexical-and-semantic-notes) but it's clearly documented [in the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/graphviz/dot.1.en.html#GRAPH_FILE_LANGUAGE).

Comment: Thank you !!
I had to use `fontname` instead of `font`. (i.e. :

`node [fontname="default-node-font"];`

`edge [fontnmae="default-edge-font"];` )

Comment: Any way to set this for all Subgraphs or clusters?